# Drupal 7: Last Modified в зависимости от Submitted by

Tags: drupal

Возможно ли использовать дату публикации контента в качестве заголовка сервера Last Modified?
Каким образом узнать переменную которая хранит дату редактирования статьи?
Каким способом воспользоваться: хук, tpl.php, модуль HTTP Response Headers?
Буду благодарен за пример кода или ссылку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tpl.php это вывод контента в браузер и никакой логики здесь никогда не должно быть, и заголовков в том числе. Это очень плохой вариант так как потом другим будет очень сложно найти это и никго не гарантирует что вывод не начнеться раньше вывода вашого шаблона. А заголовки нельзя  отправлять после начала вывода.

Выбрать хук можно в зависимости как вы выводите контент.
Вот пример кода для views, можете так же использовать pre_render для node

```
<?php

/**
 * Set the Last-Modified header to the date of the most recent post
 */

function THEME_NAME_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  switch ($view->name) {

    case 'YOURVIEWNAME' :

      if ($view->current_display == 'feed') {

        $posts = $view->result;

        drupal_add_http_header('Last-Modified', gmdate(DATE_RFC2822, $posts[0]->node_created));

      }

      break;

  }

}
```

Модуль использовать можно, но в нем я не нашел использование токенов для посдтановки например дати модификации материала. То есть вам нужно будет создать отправку заголовка и потом найти хук которым его перехватить и поставить там нужную дату. Как на меня это плохой вариант

Этот модуль используеться для статичных заголовков, а у вас динамика должна быть, лучше хуком в теме в файле template.php. Так будет потом проще найти, потому что создавать отдельный модуль по один хук нелогично и прятать этот кусочек логики в какой то другой модуль не лучшая идея.

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря ответу [Mykola Veriga](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/283873/mykola-veriga), был использован хук для ноды.

**Вот как удалось решить задачу:**

*в tamplate.php*

```
function ft_preprocess_node(&$variables){
    $variables['date'] = format_date($variables['node']->created, 'custom', 'd.m.Y - G:i'); // Перекрываем стандартный вывод даты для отображения на сайте
    $variables['submitted'] = t('Опубликовано !datetime', array('!datetime' => $variables['date']));//Перекрываем надпись Submitted by и скрываем автора
    $variables['date_lm'] = format_date($variables['node']->created, 'custom', "D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T"); // Определяем формат даты для заголовка Last Modified
    drupal_add_http_header('Last-Modified', $variables['date_lm']);//добавляем заголовок Last Modified
    $IfModifiedSince = false; //условие для IfModifiedSince
        if (isset($_ENV['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']))
            $IfModifiedSince = strtotime(substr($_ENV['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'], 5));  
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']))
            $IfModifiedSince = strtotime(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'], 5));
        if ($IfModifiedSince && $IfModifiedSince >= $variables['date_lm']) {
            drupal_add_http_header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 304 Not Modified');
        exit;
    }
}
```

**В результате получилось:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Примечание:** 
Сайт работает на nginx без apache, поэтому в виртуальном хосте должно быть добавлено:

```
location / {
        ssi on;
        ssi_last_modified on;
    }
```

Так как в nginx заголовок Last Modified по умолчанию скрыт.

Comment: используйте принятый формат для этого заголовка, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified. Эта функция поможет gmdate

Comment: Спасибо, ответ изменил: "D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T".

Comment: это "D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T" замените на DATE_RFC2822. Возможно и выйдет записать нужную строку вручную, но всеравно нужно использовать предложеную константу. Это хорошый тон :)

Comment: здесь ее можно найти поиском http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: Сервер отдает дату в формате: Date: Wed, 14 Mar 2018 15:46:23 GMT, то есть GMT на конце, а DATE_RFC2822 вместо GMT выводит +0300. Поэтому в моем случае добавлен формат даты в ручную, чтобы было единообразно.

Comment: возможно с GMT это и будет более верный формат, в такой теме точно не скажу. В таких случаях просто по доках делаю, там в Example увидел эту констатну, поэтому и написал про нее. А говорить точно в такой теме не возьмусь, это больше сторона СЕО

Comment: но всеравно вставлю свои 5 копеек) это \G\M\T можно заменить на просто Т